# Convert value to array label throughout frontend and admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, frontend, array

So i have a form that saves customer vehicle info in the database with values representing each vehicle.

I also have this array code in my model folder which should be used to display said numbers as names;

```
class Maker_Modelname_Model_Options_Vehicle_Make
{
public function toOptionArray()
{
     $vmake = array(
        array('value' => 1, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('Alfa Romeo')),
        array('value' => 2, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('AMC')),
        array('value' => 3, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('Aston Martin')),
        array('value' => 4, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('Audi')),
        array('value' => 5, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('Austin')),
        array('value' => 6, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('BMW')),
        array('value' => 7, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('Buick')),
        array('value' => 8, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('Cadillac')),
        array('value' => 9, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('Chevrolet')),
        array('value' => 10, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('Chrysler')),
        array('value' => 11, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('Citroen')),
        array('value' => 12, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('Daihatsu')),
        array('value' => 13, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('Dodge')),
        array('value' => 14, 'label' => Mage::helper('vehicle')->__('Ferrari')),

    );
return $vmake;
}
}
```

i modified the order view in the admin panel to display the customer vehicle info. I used this code to display it, but its outputs the word "**array**" which means its not reading the array properly.

```
<?php $vmake = Mage::getModel('vehicle/options_vehicle_make')
                                    ->toOptionArray(); echo $vmake[$this->htmlEscape($_order->getVehicleMake())] ?>
```

but i need the model array to convert the values to labels.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working with a multi dimensional array, so obviously it will echo `array`...

You'd need to do something like

```
echo $vmake[$this->htmlEscape($_order->getVehicleMake())]['label']
```

Also, why would you html escape the value id?

Comment: well i did do all of that... just didnt know i needed to add ['label'], which is why it wasnt working. i did remove the html escape in the official codes, the exaple had it because i modified codes that already had it. regardless, thanks. @erfan